# NMaximize giving error when trying to find global maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I've been trying to use mathematica to find the maximum of 1/(1 + e^(-(x - 9))) + 1/(1 + e^(-(y - 9)) where x>0,y>0 and x+y=100.

This is the code I've been using:

```
NMaximize[{1/(1 + e^(9 - x)) + 1/(1 + e^(9 - y)), {x + y == 100,0 < x, 0 < x}}, {x, y}]
```

However, when I run it I get this error:
[image]

Could someone please explain why I'm getting an error? I think my syntax is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, because `e` is just a symbol. You probably meant `E` the number. Changing it to `E` fixes it and it returns `{2., {x -> 50.0614, y -> 49.9386}}`

Comment: It works now thank you

Answer (score 1):

As @flinty says in the comments, `e` is a variable whereas `E` is the number.

```
NMaximize[{1/(1 + E^(9 - x)) + 1/(1 + E^(9 - y)), {x + y == 100, 0 < x, 0 < x}}, {x, y}]
```

should work fine

Comment: It works now thank you guys

Comment: @Salad20 please consider accepting the answer if it helped